# creating int[] array (with positive integers only) from String

Tags: java, arrays, string, substring, replaceall

Hey i'm having trouble creating an int[] array from Strings, which should only contain positive integers from the String.

it should do something like this:

```
INPUT: ("-5, 20,  abc, -20, defg, 45ab67, 23")
OUTPUT: [20,23]
```

I don't know how to delete this substring "45ab67". I tried using

```
Character.isDigit(c);
and
myString.replaceAll("[^\\d,-]", "");
```

It didn't work so well...

thx in advance

Answer (score 5):

Try,

```
 String input = "-5, 20, abc, -20, defg, 45ab67, 23";
 String[] arr = input.split(",");
 for (String num : arr) {
      if (num.trim().matches("\\d+")) {
        System.out.println(num);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to have a ^ and $ to prevent a string containing numbers anywhere within from matching?

Comment: @TimB, `String.matches` doesn't need boundary symbol ^ and $.

Comment: I'm willing to believe you but there is no mention of that in the Javadoc :) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: @TimB, Yes docs doesn't mentioned it. If you use `Pattern.compile()` than boundary symbol is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

1) split the string by ,
2) parse the parts (Integer.parseInt(from every part);) inside try-catch 
3) if no NumberFormatException then check if the result is > 0, if yes add it to your final list

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
String input = "-5, 20,  abc, -20, defg, 45ab67, 23"
String[] inputs = input.split(",");

int[] outputArray;
List<Integer> outputList = new ArrayList<>();

for (String in : inputs) {
    if (in.trim().matches("\\d+")) {
        outputList.add(Integer.parseInt(in.trim()));
    }
}

outputArray = outputList.toArray(new Integer[outputList.size()]);

System.out.println(outputArray);
```

Comment: You need to trim() the string before parsing it. And outputArray must be an `Integer[]`.

Comment: Wouldn't auto-boxing work for the `outputArray`? Thanks for the `.trim()` headup.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (String s: myString.split(" *, *")) {
    if (s.matches("^[0-9]+$")) {
        list.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
    }
}
int[] result = new int[list.size()];
int i = 0;
for (Integer v: list) {
    result[i++] = v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(^| )(\\d+)(,|$)").matcher(s);
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] getArray(String s) {
    String[] parts = s.split(", ");
    ArrayList<Integer> resultArray = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String part : parts) {
        if (part.matches("\\d+")) {
            resultArray.add(Integer.parseInt(part));
        }
    }
    int[] result = new int[resultArray.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.size(); i++) {
        result[i] = resultArray.get(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```